# Play framework 2, AngularJS and internationalization

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I'm currently implementing AngularJS in a Play framework 2 application, and it's good so far, but I'm facing some problems with internationalization. I have my messages files (`messages.en`, `messages.fr`, etc) that I was using normally without Angular in my scala templates.

Now, I'm using Angular partials...So I found a plugin (`jsMessages`) for Play framework to use the messages file in a javascript file, I finally found a way to use it with `requireJs` and all that stuff.

So, now I'm passing the `Messages` function (which allows to get translated messages) in the `$scope` variable. That way I can retrieve the message with `{{Messages("myMessage")}}`, but it doesn't work everywhere.

For example, some of my `<input>` have default value (like a placeholder, with a translated message too). But Angular doesn't like it and does not evaluate the expression.

So, I'm wondering what should I do :

- should I use the Play server to template the pages with the strings already translated server-side, which would be returned to Angular to use them as "partials"? (mix Scala `@` directives and Angular `ng-*` directives in the same templates)
- or should I use only javascript to have the strings translated, and in some cases, pass an extra variable to the scope, just for the inputs, textarea and all these components where `{{}}` cannot be used directly ?

(I personally prefer the first option)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good solution to use the Play templating system. This way you can also use Scala if you need to put a bit of logic in your templates or also access your Play configuration file.

But if you want to be totally decoupled from the Liferay framework jsMessage can be a good solution. To make it work, try to put jsMessage function on the $root scope in order to make it available form everywhere.

To do this add the jsMessage Messages function to the root scope when your main application module is run (ng-app directive).

```
angular.module('app').run(function ($rootScope) {
    //Put the jsMessage function in the root scope in order to be able to call
    //{{ Messages('my.messages') }} from the templates.
    $rootScope.Messages = window.Messages;
});
```